# PHP PostgreSQL Only works from command line

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the following code.  The code runs all the way through from command line, but only gets to 'about to connect' when called from the web.  What causes this difference?

```
<?php

echo 'about to connect';

$con=pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx") or die ('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());


echo 'connected!';
echo $con;
echo $db;
$query = "SELECT VERSION()";
$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");
$row = pg_fetch_row($rs);

echo $row[0] . "\n";

pg_close($con);

?>
```

**EDIT**
The command
"sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql"
fixed the problem.  No idea why.

Comment: Adding the port might do something.

Comment: Editing file hba.conf may help you.

Comment: host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx" did not do anything